# CSS Non-positioned boxes

Tags: css, dom, position

So, I am reading through the CSS spec on W3 site, and I come across the use of the word "non-positioned" which I am having a hard time picturing. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#float-rules  Please see below use.

> Since a float is not in the flow, **non-positioned** block boxes created
>   before and after the float box flow vertically as if the float did not
>   exist. However, the current and subsequent line boxes created next to
>   the float are shortened as necessary to make room for the margin box
>   of the float.

please take a look at my sample on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Kobo/7ASjk/

```
<div class="case two">
    <div class="F">Block F</div>
    <div class="B">Block B</div>
    <div class="C">Block C</div>
</div>
```

My question is/are,

- what is a non-positioned box in CSS context? Is it a box in
  normal-flow? Or a box that does not have style property position
  explicitly set?
- What does the first paragraph up there mean? I mean what does the spec. mean by the

  > "current and subsequent line-boxes created next to the float are
  >   shortened to make room for the margin box of the floated-box"

  when the floated-box is OUT-OF-FLOW?

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: The first one definitely sounds like using a box without the position property explicitly set.

Comment: I made that assumption myself but when I tested the assumption, it failed on the second part of the statement.

Comment: In the top example, did you mean that a box is normal-flow will always appear below a floated-box? Because the floated-box in that example appears above the normal-flowed box.

Comment: But if you switched the location of the boxes( normal-flow box declared before the floated-box) you find that the normal-flow box appears above the floated box in that case. or am I missing something here?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47533/discussion-between-kobojunkie-and-adrift)

Answer (score 1):

> what is a non-positioned box in CSS context?

It's a box in a normal flow.

> current and subsequent line-boxes created next to the float are
>   shortened to make room for the margin box of the floated-box

Line boxes are blocks created around lines of text. As you can see in your fiddle the Block B text is moved to the right in relation to its parent element. This is because floated Block F is in the way - it shortens Block B line boxes and moves them to the right by the amount equal to F's margin box.

Line boxes can be seen with the help of an outline:

```
<div class="B"><span>Block B</span></div>
span {
    outline: 2px solid cyan;
}
```

(see a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2VSPy/1/)

Take a look how this outline sticks to the text (instead of forming a rectangle)